# PHP form validation and submit to paypal for payment

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

can someone please help me on this :)

I have a form to submit a classified ad. The form uses PHP for validation.
In the form there is a drop down menu where one can select its payment according to the display time of the ad.

I don't know how to keep the validation in place and only send to Paypal if everything is ok.
Is it possible to do it in one step?

Or do I have to redirect the user to a confirmation page and there place my buy now button?
Also I would like to use IPN to update the info in the DB.
Thanks
Max

Answer (score 0):

The [PayPal IPN document](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf) describes how you should do it.

Comment: Thanks Stillstanding I think my problem comes before the IPN part. I need to validate first and then send the buttom POST variables to Paypal for payment. Can it be done in one stage? If not then what is the recommended flow? Thanks

Comment: If, by "one stage", you mean no intermediate page changes (confirmation page), it's really dependent on the monetary transaction. If user has to enter an amount, then he/she deserves to find out if the amount you're deducting from PayPal is indeed the amount he/she entered in the form. If it's a fixed amount, the confirmation page is totally unnecessary. It's just a formality to confirm first, so the user isn't surprised.

Comment: Then make it a single-click transaction. But u still need a "thank you" page.

Comment: By one stage I mean validation and Paypal transaction with one click when I post the ad. Where I find it difficult is that my form action performs the validation process (in PHP which now just inserts the data in the DB table) so how can I have the pay now button action triggered when the validation succeeds? (BTW the amounts are fixed and indicated in the drop down text.)

Comment: Look here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/blog/web-form/91/submit-form-multiple-scripts/